# Inventory and orders

Tags: order-status, inventory

Is there any addon that will take an order from pending to prepaired to ship when an item that has been ordered comes into stock?

Comment: tony, in magento you cannot place an order without stock

Comment: @AmitBera of course you can, if you enable backorders in the system configuration or per product.

Comment: @tony Would like some more info before I start coding. Should stock be reduced when the shipment is created?

Answer (score 4):

Note to self:

- allow products in backorder
- run cron daily to check processing orders older than 1 day for all items in stock
- if all in stock decrease product stock with qty to ship
- use sales service model to convert order to shipment and send out shipment

Will come back to this asap. Need to go to have some rest to work it out first :)

Comment: Should make an extension for this on github